# C++ - Thread for socket server

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, sockets, server

I'm trying to implement a server, which runs in his own thread.
Later, the server should work together with another thread.
Is that even possible?

My current attempt to implement this:

main

```
#include "EtherServer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    EtherServer* es = new EtherServer();
    es->init();
    return 0;
}
```

Server.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#ifndef ETHERSERVER_H_
#define ETHERSERVER_H_

class EtherServer
{
    public:
        bool init();
        static void* runServer(void *arg);
        static void sigchld_handler(int s);
        static void* get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa);

        static int s_sockfd;

    private:

};

#endif /* ETHERSERVER_H_ */
```

Server.cpp

```
#include "EtherServer.h"

#define PORT "31107"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

int EtherServer::s_sockfd = 0;

void EtherServer::sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    // waitpid() might overwrite errno, so we save and restore it:
    int saved_errno = errno;

    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);

    errno = saved_errno;
}


// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void* EtherServer::get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

bool EtherServer::init()
{
    int rv;
    int yes=1;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((EtherServer::s_sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(EtherServer::s_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, yes,                      
            sizeof(int)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(EtherServer::s_sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) 
        {
            close(EtherServer::s_sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure
    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        exit(1);

    }

    if (listen(EtherServer::s_sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    struct sigaction sa;

    sa.sa_handler = EtherServer::sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    pthread_attr_t attr_baseb;
    (void)pthread_attr_init(&attr_baseb);
    (void)pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr_baseb, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    (void)pthread_create(NULL, &attr_baseb, &runServer, (void *)this);
}

void* EtherServer::runServer(void *arg)
{
    int new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    //struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        sleep(1);
        new_fd = accept(EtherServer::s_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, EtherServer::get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            int n;
            char buffer[256];
            bzero(buffer, 256);
            close(EtherServer::s_sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener

            while (n = read(new_fd, buffer, 255) > 0)
            {

                if (send(new_fd, buffer, 255, 0) == -1)
                    perror("send");
            }
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
            sleep(1);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific question you have about this?

Comment: I don't know why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: You must be more specific, what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thread runs as a child of main(). When you return from main its child threads are killed, too.

Rather than return, main will have to perform some wait operation of its own, so that it will only exit cleanly when all child threads have completed.